# Eclipse - System property http.nonProxyHosts

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm using Android ADT bundle V22.6.2 on my iMac and I keep getting the following message:

System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences.

I tried to reinstall it and even tried different versions of Eclipse but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me solve this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try renaming some of your filenames / folders, so they won't have irregular characters (%$#..) or basically any characters that are not in English.

[**Source**](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/144975/java-error-when-loading-a-local-workspace)